# Using moment.js with jint

Tags: jint

I would like to use moment.js with jint.  I have tried several alternatives, but always end up with this error:

> Self referencing loop detected for property 'Engine' with type 'Jint.Engine'. Path '_locale.ordinal.Target.Scope.Record.Engine.GlobalEnvironment.Record